# How to calculate total price of multiple items in cart?

Tags: javascript, php, html, user-interface, frontend

***Hello, Im trying to calculate cart total using JavaScript but it is showing the total for the first item only! Any help please?***

### This is my JS Code

```
  <script>
    function f(){
      var price = $('#unitprice').val();
      var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
      total = price*quantity;
      $('#total').val(total);
      return;
    };
  </script>
```

### HTML PHP

```
<td class="p-price first-row"><?php echo 'LBP '.number_format($r['product_price'],0)?>/KG</td>

 <input type="hidden" id="unitprice"  value="<?php echo $r['product_price']?>" onload="f();">

<input type="text"  id="quantity" value="<?php echo $weight ?>" readonly onload="f();">

<td class="total-price first-row"><input id="total" readonly style="border:none; color:#e7ab3c; text-align:center;  font-weight: bold;"></td>
```

---

[This is my work, check the image please!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29cFB.png)

Any idea how to work it out?

Grand total solution will be appreciated also! Thank you

Comment: why didn't you use server-side code to manipulate prices?

Comment: IDs must be unique to the document. If there are multiple pairs of those inputs, I suggest using classes and iterating through them with JavaScript to perform the calculation on each pair. Also most of the `onload` events will be redundant; it would be more efficient to run the function once when the document loads.

Comment: Like that : [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/nVCY4/26/) ?

Comment: how can I use server-side code to manipulate total?

Comment: can a loop fix this problem?

Comment: You should loop through the items in the cart and then multiple quantities with a unit price for each item. Store it in a variable and sum up to get the grand total. Note that, you cannot use ID filter to get multiple items since it will be (Should be) unique in your HTML.

Comment: Can you please explain? I'm a beginner